# Getting empty .eml file using redemption safe mail method.

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I am using redemption to convert outlook mailitem object into .eml file. It is saving .eml file but having empty containts. My code is as below.

```
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
            SafeMailItem test = new SafeMailItem();
            test.Item = mailItem;

            test.SaveAs(@"E:\test13.eml", Redemption.RedemptionSaveAsType.olRFC822);
```

Comment: "Empty" as in "file of 0 length"? Or as in "does not contain all the data that I expect"?  Where does Item variable come from? Did you save it first?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I am getting file of length 1Kb but when i opened that file using outlook it didnot contains any element like subject,attachments,to. I am getting empty file.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Item variable comes from outlook send button event. It contains data i inspected while debugging.

Comment: Have you tried to open the file in Notepad? Make sure you save the Outlook item first (mailItem.Save) to make sure the data is visible to MAPI.